# how to transform dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, transpose

I have the following snippet from a dataframe:

```
           cough      fever  
8            0.0        0.0  
9           -1.0        1.0  
24           0.0        1.0  
29           0.0       -1.0  
30           1.0        1.0
```

Where I need to sum up each column by each value, like:

```
df['cough'].value_counts()
Out[189]:
 0.0    3
 1.0    1
-1.0    1
Name: cough, dtype: int64

df['fever'].value_counts()
Out[189]:
 0.0    1
 1.0    3
-1.0    1
Name: fever, dtype: int64
```

However, I need this in a dataframe, which I was able to do as per:

```
out=pd.DataFrame()
symptoms=['cough', 'fever']
for s in symptoms:
     frames=[out, df[c].value_counts().to_frame()]
     out=pd.concat(frames)
```

But, the output has empty cells:

```
         cough    fever
 0.0       3        NaN
-1.0       1        NaN
 1.0       1        NaN
 0.0       NaN      1
 1.0       NaN      1
-1.0       NaN      3
```

How do I get the df in the form below (that is eliminate empty cells and transpose, all in one fell swoop)?

```
          -1    0    1     
 cough     1    3    1
 fever     1    1    3
```

Comment: Including an `axis` argument in your `concat` should do the trick, or use a `join` instead

Comment: Cool! So simple. Thanks! Transposing it should be a piece of cake now.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe do it in one go. See code below

```
 df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T#if cough and fever are not dtype object



#df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T#if cough and fever are dtype object



         -1.0  0.0  1.0
cough     1    3    1
fever     1    1    3
```

Comment: Was this heelpful?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `concat`

```
out=pd.concat(frames ,axis=1)
```

Or simply do

```
s = df.melt()
out = pd.crosstab(s.variable,s.value)
value     -1.0   0.0   1.0
variable                  
cough        1     3     1
fever        1     1     3
```

Comment: I would accept this as the answer, but @G. Anderson deserves the win.

Comment: @horcle_buzz ha ~ that is ok ~

Comment: @horcle_buzz also add more simple way than for loop

Comment: I like your second method.